# How to define R squared on a subset of the original sample?

Tags: regression, anova, linear-model, r-squared

Suppose I fit a linear model

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

and I can derive the coefficient of determination, also known as the R squared, by calculating

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}}$$

where

$$SS_{res}=\Sigma e_i^2$$ and

$$SS_{tot}=\Sigma (y_i-\bar{y})^2$$

Now I also want to know how well the $e>0$ side and $e<0$ side fits, respectively. Is there a measure to determine the "R squared" of a linear model on a subset of the original sample which also results in $[0,1]$?

I notice there's a concept called *partial R squared* but it is about measuring the fitness of a subset of regressors rather than a sub-sample.

Answer (score 1):

$$R^2 = \dfrac{SSTot-SSRes}{SSTot}$$

Let's break down what those mean.

$$SSTot = \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2$$

The regression that you're doing wants to predict the mean of the distribution of your response variable *conditioned* on some predictors. In the absence of knowing anything about how your data are generated, why not guess the overall mean? $SSTot$ is the total sum of squares and measures your error when you use the overall mean of $y$ as the prediction, no matter what predictors you have. This may be a naive approach, but it's a good baseline.

$$SSRes = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y})^2$$

However, now that you've run your regression, you think you have more insight than you did when you were just guessing the overall mean of all $y$ values. Now see how much error you have when you use your predictions from the regression!

With those two values calculated, you can do the arithmetic to find $R^2$. Now, you want to do it on a subset of the data. I see two options. Let there be $j$-many observations in your subset.

1) $\dfrac{\sum_j (y_j - \bar{y})^2 - \sum_j (y_j - \hat{y})^2}{\sum_j (y_j - \bar{y})^2}$

2) $\dfrac{\sum_j (y_j - \bar{y}_{subset})^2 - \sum_j (y_j - \hat{y})^2}{\sum_j (y_j - \bar{y}_{subset})^2}$

The first option uses the same average value as you get when you look at the whole data set, while the second computes the average of your subset. I think I can squint and see a reason to do option #2, but I wouldn't do it. $R^2$ is a way of measuring how you do compared to naively guessing the overall mean, so I'd want to see how each subset does compared to guessing the overall mean.

Edit: Thinking about it more, I completely reject option #2. If you want to compare to the mean of the subset, rerun the regression on just the subset and calculate $R^2$ the usual way, but then you're not using the same regression equation or even the same significant parameters (it's a totally different problem).

Answer (score 0):

R-squared (R2) can be calculated as:

R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)

so if you can calculate these variance values for the data subset, it should work as you want.